# how to know which pin is being used, change pin?

Tags: arduino-uno

i am having an issue where i am unsure how my device knows what pins its using. Version #1 is a timeclock which is simply declared with no pin numbers. Version #2 is a simple loop with a device on pin A0;

So how can i set / change the pins for the clock to use. Currently it is on A4 & A5.

If i wanted to move the clock to say pins.. A1 and A2, how would i do that?

Thanks

Version #1-------------------------------------------------

```
// Date and time functions using a DS1307 RTC connected via I2C and Wire lib
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 RTC;

void setup () {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Wire.begin();
    RTC.begin();

  if (! RTC.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
 //   RTC.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));
  }

}

void loop () {

    DateTime now = RTC.now();

    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
}
```

Version #2---------------------------------------------------------

```
int powerswitch1 = A0;
void setup() 
{
pinMode(powerswitch1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop ()
{

digitalWrite(powerswitch1, HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(powerswitch1, LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(powerswitch1, HIGH);
delay(500);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion is over the multiple functions of analog pins A4 and A5.

In addition to being analog pins, they are also the pins configured internally for I2C/TWI serial, which is interfaced with using the Wire library on arduino. Since those are the only two pins Wire can use, there is no need to specify them, the sketch just calls `Wire.begin()` to set everything up.

If you need a second I2C device you can simply connect them both up to A4 and A5 at the same time, the protocol is designed to support that kind of thing. If you need to use A4 and A5 for something else besides I2C, you can't continue to use the hardware I2C library.

It is possible to use a software implementation of I2C/TWI serial on other pins, but usually soft-serial implementation have some drawbacks compared to the hardware version. There is an implementation on the arduino playground here: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SoftwareI2CLibrary

That said, the RTC library you are using seems to internally use the Wire library, so it would take some hacking to switch it to a different I2C implementation.